# parent find or siblings or next wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to fill the value of an input after you click a button.

The only way I can get this to work is if I target the id of the input, the problem is I will be doing this many times over so I want to use `parent().find()` instead of hardcoding the id.

HTML:

```
<div class="inner-box">
    <div class="mark-as-paid <?php echo 'paid' ?>">Paid</div>
    <input id="mark_as_paid" name="mark_as_paid" type="text" value="<?php echo $final_result[0]; ?>" class="mark_as_paid"></input>
</div>
```

AJAX:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

     $('.mark-as-paid').click(function() {

         var paid_value = 'Paid';

         $.ajax({
             url: 'http://localhost/myshop/owe_money/add_paid.php',
             type: 'post',
             data: {
                 paid_value: paid_value
             },
             beforeSend: function() {
                 $("#ajax-result").html('Before');
             },

             success: function(data) {

                 $("#ajax-result").html(data);


                 $(this).parent().find('.mark_as_paid').val('Paid');



             },
             error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                 $("#ajax-result").html('Error');
             }
         });



     });
 });
```

I have also tried

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.mark_as_paid').val('Paid');
```

and

```
$(this).parent().siblings('input').val('Paid');
```

and

```
$(this).next('input').val('Paid');
```

For the siblings one I get an error in the console `TypeError: a.parentNode is undefined`

The only one that seems to work is

```
$('#mark_as_paid').val('Paid');
```

But that's no use to me as I will be putting that HTML in a `for` loop and generating many inputs so I want to target each one separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.mark-as-paid').click(function () {
        var paid_value = 'Paid';
        var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/myshop/owe_money/add_paid.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                paid_value: paid_value
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#ajax-result").html('Before');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#ajax-result").html(data);
                $this.parent().find('.mark_as_paid').val('Paid');
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                $("#ajax-result").html('Error');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

What I changed:

- inside a ajax call `this` is not what you expected, so cache it outside with `var $this = $(this);`